# petapoco query a Sql Server View

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke, petapoco, dotnetnuke-7

I have started using the DAL2 with dotnetnuke 7.  I have some complicated queries that I have created views for in the SQL server database that my instance uses.  What is the best practice for accessing a simple select from these views.

If I use the following then does this bypass the dbOwner and ObjectQualifier:

```
    Public Function GetProducts_Short_Active() As IEnumerable(Of Object)
        Using ctx As IDataContext = DataContext.Instance
            Return ctx.ExecuteQuery(Of Object)(CommandType.Text, "SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_ProductList_Short_Active", Nothing)
        End Using
    End Function
```

**QUESTION:**
Or should I define a class and properties for each sql-server-view (like I did for each table) with the table name annotation being the name of the view like below?

```
<TableName("vw_ProductList_Short_Active")> _
<PrimaryKey("ProductId")> _
<Cacheable("ProductList_Short_Active", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)> _
<Scope("PortalId")>
Public Class ProductList_Short_Active
     ''view properties go here
End Class
```

### EDIT 1:

[This article](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/203/threadid/480781/scope/posts) seems to indicate that I should not use a view, but rather extend my product class with ignorable columns of iEnumerable that represent the "joined" data records I need.  Is that accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this a few ways.

If you don't need to update or insert into the view's tables, I would think using the view is a good way to do it.  I have successfully used a view as a DAL2 table, but even if it is schema-bound, only GETs will work.  If you are just reading data, that is the best way to do it.

I have also done it is with joining child data from the respoitory method.
In [this article](http://www.dotnetnuclear.com/articles/tabid/88/ID/10/Advanced-DotNetNuke-Rich-Client-Modules--Knockoutjs-jQuery-and-Services-Framework.aspx) (full source code is in the Related files section), I have a DAL2 object based on a table with an ignorecolumn attribute.

```
[TableName("DNNuclear_DataVisualizer_Chart")]
[PrimaryKey("ChartId", AutoIncrement = true)]
[Cacheable("Charts", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)]
[Scope("ModuleId")]
public class Chart
{
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    public int ChartId { get; set; }
...
    [IgnoreColumn]
    public IList<SeriesData> SeriesData { get; set; }
...
```

}

That attribute gets filled in the DAL2 repository method.

```
   public Chart GetItem(int itemId)
   {
       Chart t;
       using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
       {
           var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Chart>();
           t = rep.GetById(itemId);
           var repD = ctx.GetRepository<ChartData>();
           var data = repD.Get(itemId);
           if (data != null && data.Count() > 0)
           {
               // Get unique categories
               var uniqueCategories = data.OrderBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => x.Category).Distinct();
               t.Categories = uniqueCategories.ToList();

               // Get series data
               t.SeriesData = getSeriesData(data, t.Categories.ToArray<string>());
           }
       }
       return t;
   }
```

Comment: great, this is what I was thinking, just wanted to make sure I didn't head off and get too deep in the wrong direction.  The video/article that you linked to was excellent.  It would be nice if DNN corp put more effort into their DAL2 wiki as it is an essential part of the core.  The simple CRUD operations for simple poco's is easy, but real life modules are usually more complicated than this.  And a few simple examples like getting static data from a sql-view would have been nice.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Just to follow up, have you used a sql view (defined as a peta poco table) with a CacheItemPriority?  I am using it and the cache is never reset even after the 20 min timeout.  See this post: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/dnn-7-dal-2-clear-cache-for-object-based-on-sql-view