# One to Many Relationship with PetaPoco DNN7 DAL2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, petapoco, dotnetnuke-7

I am developing a module and I understand PetaPoco with single tables within the DNN7 architecture.  I still can't quite figure out how I should be handling One to Many Database relationships.  I have 3 tables, Product, Options and ProductMappings table, where that table maps the product to many options.  For petapoco I have a product class, productcontroller clas, and same thing for the options.  Now when I get to the Productmappings table should I have a class and controller class for that or is there another way I should be handling this?  I am sure there is an easier way and google searches are not specific enough, they tell me how to get things out of a mappings table (one to many) but don't tell me the right way to populate it.  If anyone could lead me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: We discussed some ways about doing relationships in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503264/petapoco-query-a-sql-server-view/20520474#20520474

Comment: I think my original question is not clear.  I have one product with many options.  I have a table for product and a table for option.  My third table then has product_id and option_id.  I can then link the product to multiple options.  Basically I am using a normalized table layout.  I need to be able to do CRUD on that third table too.  I am not seeing the info I need in that post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a class, so PetaPoco can map the DB results into objects of that class. A controller is not need if you won't interact with that class from the front-end.

Comment: I will interact with the class because I need to save the options.  Basically when a user edits the product they will be able to select what options the product has.  So I need to have those in the table that will hold the productid with each optionid.

Answer (score 0):

On DNN9+ I had no way to get it working except by using a column with "IgnoreColumn" attribute and loading the value from the other entity repository (loop if required)