# Establish one-to-many relation for populating data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm new to MVC, so this may be basic and I need some pointers. 
I started building a module from Chris Hammond's module template for DNN8 MVC. The template has code for manipulating a single model. I want to have two models and a one-to-many relation between them, and that both are populated at the same time.

Model1:

```
[TableName("Model1")]
[PrimaryKey("Model1Id", AutoIncrement = true)]
[Cacheable("Models", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)]
[Scope("ModuleId")]
public class Model1
{
    public Model1()
    {
        listModel2 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Model2>();
    }
    public int Model1Id { get; set; } = -1;
    public string Model1Name { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.List<Model2> listModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

Model2:

```
[TableName("Model2")]
[PrimaryKey("Model2Id", AutoIncrement = true)]
[Scope("Model1Id")]
public class Model2
{
    public int Model2Id { get; set; }            
    public int Model1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Model1 Model1 { get; set; }    
}
```

Below is the code that populates data using features provided by DNN. I have only modified it, I'm still following the basic principle illustrated in the template.

```
public Model1 GetModel1(int moduleId)
{
    Model1 m;
    using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
    {
        var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Model1>();
        m = rep.Get().Where<Model1>(l => l.ModuleId == moduleId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return m;
}
```

I get a runtime error: Invalid columname listModel2. Removing this variable from the Model1 class results in the module working as expected. The error is on the `rep.Get()` line.

I believe that I need to somehow establish that Model1 and Model2 are two entities of a one-to-many relationship, and that listModel2 is not a column in the database, but a separate table that needs to be populated based on Model1Id foreign key relationship. How do I do that?

In other words, what is the best way to populate the listModel2 collection without writing data access code - like other properties of Model1 class are populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since listModel2 is not an actual column in your table, you need to add an [IgnoreColumn] decorator above the attribute. See my answer in this stackoverflow question for more details: [petapoco query a Sql Server View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503264/petapoco-query-a-sql-server-view/20520474#20520474)

Comment: Thank you Scott! Is the repository Get() efficient when there is a large number of records? I am expecting the Model2 to grow and want to use the right approach from the start. In the other answer you linked, all records in repository are being fetched and filtered in code using Linq - that part concerns me a bit. Appreciate your input.

Comment: depending on your use case, you can use stored procedures in SQL and map them to petapoco objects, then perform some of the filtering in your stored procedure. I agree that linq filter and sort on large sets is slow.  In order to execute a stored procedure you map the procedure name as the peta poco table name and the output columns the same as the table columns.  Then use the ExecuteQuery function of the data context and supply the command type as procedure, command name and expected input parameters.

Comment: Thanks @JKing, I will give that a try.

Comment: Another thing you can do is create 3 repositories and models, one based on a data view that is a join of the tables, and the other 2 repositories for the individual tables.  You would just use the name of the view in the TableName attribute for the model and the repository will only contain gets.